# If Bind is fundamental to monads, how come we don't use more SelectMany in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming, monads

If Bind is fundamental to monads, how come we don't use more SelectMany in Linq?

*(Sorry, can't think of anything useful to add to the question)*

Comment: I recommend reading this blog - good stuff : http://igoro.com/archive/one-linq-operator-to-rule-them-all/

Comment: @Moberg, very nice and compliments Jon's answer nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `SelectMany` is crucial in that many other things *can* be expressed that way - but that doesn't mean it's always the most concise way of expressing it. You can think of `Select`, `Where` and so on as merely convenience methods... but ones which are *so* convenient that we often don't need the most flexible form.

To give another example, `Aggregate` can perform all the aggregation you want - but `Max`, `Count` etc are far more common.

Comment: What he said, it's a matter of simplicity over flexibility.

Comment: I suspected that was the answer. I seem to remember someone from the Rx team saying that all of the operators could be implemented using `Zip` (IIRC).

Answer (score 2):

Note that every time you have two `from`s in a Linq query, you're calling `SelectMany`.

http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/30/c-3-0-query-expression-translation-cheat-sheet.aspx